# C++ - Deleting array passed as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I'm having unexpected behavior with this function:

```
void myClass1::expandArray(myClass2 *arr, int newSize) //myClass1 is friend of myClass2
{
    myClass2 *temp = new myClass2[newSize];
    /*fill temp with data*/
    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp;
    capacity = newSize; //capacity is a data member of the class
}
```

This function executes correctly at first, then (which is what puzzles me the most) *either at the second or the third times it's called*, it just freezes, **no feedback at all** until a few minutes later the program crashes.

I have a version in which the array is a private member of the class and it's not passed as a parameter and it works normally.

Comment: Can you create an [mcve]?

Comment: u now, just use `std:.vector`

Comment: Smells like you are deleting the same array more than once or use deleted array. Replace your dynamic array with `std::vector` and never see this problem again.

Comment: Don't tell him to use `std::vector`, besides the fact that it sucks, it doesn't answer his question. @maja, post the full code that reproduces your problem, we need to see what arrays are being used and how to give you an answer.

Comment: @ocket8888 What "sucks" about a `std::vector`?

Comment: They're featureless and require you to create iterators to perform basic operations.

Comment: @ocket8888 What basic operations does vector make you create iterators for.  You should be able to use a vector exactly like an array.

Comment: @ocket8888, what a misguided approach... std::vector is feature-rich, drop-in replacement for any C-style dynamic arrays. In fact, there is exactly 0 reasons to use C-style dynamic arrays nowadays.

Comment: I'd really rather not get into it, it's not what comments are for, and it's beside the point. Telling him to use something else, whatever it is, instead of what he's doing should only be done if what he's doing results in undefined behaviour, and it should never be done without an explanation. He's not asking how you would do it, he's asking why his way isn't working.

Comment: You are not passing the pointer by reference

Comment: at this point I don't have time to rewrite everything using vectors..  in fact, I would have better used linked lists for what I'm doing, but at design time I didn't consider some of the features I had to implement with this program

Comment: @maja it's usually best to `delete` things in the same scope they are made in, in general.

Comment: @ocket8888, if one asks me how to scratch his left ear with right hand, making sure the hand passess under the right knee, I feel free to suggest achieving the same result using other technique.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm sorry I besmirched the name of `std`, I really don't care that you like it. When someone asks me "how to scratch his left ear with right hand, making sure the hand passes under the right knee," I would also suggest that they do it a different way, but not without first telling them what they're doing wrong and answering the question they asked instead of ignoring it. And it **really is beside the point** but using `std::vector` is not _always_ better than just a plain pointer. I don't pretend to know the context in which this function needs to be used.

Comment: @ocket8888, care to provide a scenario where using a new[] allocated pointer is better (in any technical way) than vector?

Comment: @SergeyA No. Comments are not for personal discussions; this will my last post in response to you and I make it only because ignoring you would be rude. If you have something more to say I'd suggest saying it in chat, which **is** for discussions.

Comment: Maja, I'd shy away from linked lists as well, even `std::list`. The cost of 0(1) insert and delete on modern computing hardware is almost always dwarfed by the increased costs incurred by iterating through a linked list. There is often no spatial locality between nodes resulting in very poor cache performance. As always, profile the code to find out. Your case may fall into almost never camp and see significant performance improvement. It's just a lot more likely to not to.

Comment: The other potential issue with the expandArray function using `new[]` is that it's dumb -- it shouldn't need to resize anything if the current capacity hasn't been exceeded.  Ex:  You allocate 100, then you resize down to 1 -- that's two calls to the allocator when the first one is all you needed. Using `std::vector` and `resize()` is smarter in that it doesn't do the memory management this naively.  This could be a big deal if `expandArray` is called a good number of times using the same pointer.  Essentially you need two distinct member variables, one for size, the other, capacity.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm dealing with sparse matrices

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not sure I understand: the function is called only if the used terms index is equal to the capacity index

Comment: @maja You didn't post the rest of your code.  From the little code you posted, it gives the impression that this function is called, regardless of the value of `newSize`.  But I would seriously use `std::vector` here -- all your problems should go away if you did that, and none of the checking for capacity needs to be done.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if a linked list was anything but a performance killer for a sparse matrix. A note on the pointer-to-array, make sure that anything managing that array is [Rule of Three compliant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). One of the great things about `std::vector` is it handles this (and the Rule of Five) for you.

Comment: @user4581301 after wasting 4 hours on a related problem I switched to vectors, took me 45 min.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest edit the problem is very clear. Function deletes original array, and than copies a local pointer - not affecting original pointer in any way. As a result, it keeps pointing to (now deleted) original array.

example:

```
int* my_arr = new int[10];
expandArray(my_arr, 25);
my_arr[0] = 5; // crash-boom-bang! my_arr still points to the same memory as it did before expandArray was called!
```

Solution - as I said in the comments, use `std::vector`. All neccessary resize(s) will be handled for you.

If you are hellbent on using C-style dynamic arrays, you should pass your pointer via reference, i.e.

```
void expandArray(MyClass*& arr, size_t sz);
```

Comment: it turns out the corrected code works for an array (which is data member) and crashes for another (declared inside another member function)..